# Search For Custom Post Type and Custom Fields

Tags: search

I have an `events` custom post type. I have custom fields such as `start date, end date, venue` etc. I'm building up a custom search specifically for this post type. So far I have this

**functions.php**

```
 function wpse18703_posts_where( $where, &$wp_query )
{
    global $wpdb;
    if ( $wpse18703_title = $wp_query->get( 'wpse18703_title' ) ) {
        $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE \'' . $wpdb->esc_like( $wpse18703_title )  . '%\'';
    }
    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpse18703_posts_where', 10, 2 );

function searchfilterevent($query) {
    $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
        $args = array(
            'numberposts'   => -1,
            'wpse18703_title'   => 'reading festival',
            'post_type'     => 'event'
        );
    if ($query->is_search && $post_type == 'event' ) {
        $query->set($args);
    }

return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','searchfilterevent');
```

So when I go to `/?s=dklfjskldfj&post_type=event` I expect to see a list of results of custom post type `event` with the title of `reading festival`.

Can anyone suggest why I'm not?

Comment: it looks like you miss the first `%` after `LIKE`

Comment: That's fine for my example as the events I want back all start with 'reading festival'

Comment: I don't think `wpse18703_title` is a valid argument for `$query`, either for get or set, nor is `$wpse18703_title` defined so how can it equal anything.

Comment: It helps to print the whole $wp_query after everyting is done and see the actual SQL-Statement if there is a problem, but it doesn't look like. I don't see a problem with wpse..._title, but I wonder about numberposts, you will need 'posts_per_page' there I guess. But I have no solution so far.

Comment: but make sure, you still use wpdb->prepare (see https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb/esc_like) for security reasons.

Comment: I think you need to focus on this `$query->set($args);` why?

Comment: I want to pass the arguments to the query

Comment: I mean why your argument in array?, `$query->set` have 2 arguments, pair key and value.